# How do you join two KeyedTuple objects in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following two queries

```
res=session.query(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

res_t=session.query(t_marketing_time_stat_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_time_stat_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

try:
    return res.one() + res_t.one()
except NoResultFound as e:
    return None
```

`res` and `res_t` are both of type `sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple` which support addition, however, the resulting object is a simple tuple, without keys.

I would like to have a combined result, so I did the following:

```
rv = {}
res=session.query(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

res_t=session.query(t_marketing_time_stat_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_time_stat_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

try:
    res =res.one()
    res_t = res_t.one()
    for k in res.keys():
        rv[k] = getattr(res, k)
    for k in res_t.keys():
        rv[k] = getattr(res_t, k)
except NoResultFound as e:
    return None
```

While this works, I suspect there is a built-in way, or a better way of achieving this with sqlalchemy. I Would be happy to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct new [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html?highlight=keyedtuple#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) instantly from two query results like below:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.util import KeyedTuple
>>> res = KeyedTuple(a + b, a.keys() + b.keys())
```

Comment: Just a note: [`KeyedTuple` has been replaced with `Row`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html?highlight=keyedtuple#change-4710-orm) in 1.4+ .